# Getting content from two stdObject array

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

```
[responseheader] => Object (
    Array ( 
        [0] =>  Object ( 
            [id] => id_1 
            [name] => abc 
        )
        [1] => Object ( 
            [id] => id_2 
            [name] => xyz 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
[response] => Object ( 
    [id_1] => Object ( 
        [content] => Array ( 
            [0] => content_1 
            ) 
        ) 
    [id_2] => Object ( 
        [content] => Array ( 
            [0] => content_2
        )
    )
)
```

Both the above 2 objects, `responseheader` and `response` are under one object (`header`).

In the above structure, the order is for `response` will be same as it is in `responseheader`.(ie, id_2 will always come after `id_1`)

I want to get the `content` from `response` for each `id` present in `responseheader`. I will be iterating `responseheader` object.

I could loop through `response` and progressively add another property (say `dummy`) inside `responseheader` storing the `content`, but is there any better, faster approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$result = array();
//loop through responseheader array
foreach($data['responseheader'] as $row)
{
    //if the id exists in the response array add it to the result array
    if(array_key_exists($row['id'], $data['response'])) {
        $result[] = $data['response'][$row['id']]['content'][0];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

If the content in response could contain more than one content you have to loop throught it to:

```
foreach($data['response'][$row['id']]['content'] as $content) {
    $result[] = $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There will only be one `content` under each `id_*` object. 
Is there any way, to add the content to the respective `id` in `responseheader`? There are many other fields in it, therefore I will be iterating `responseheader`.

Comment: Yeah sure. Just add it to the `$row` instead of the result array.